# Finding the position of the maximum element

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there a standard function that returns the position (not value) of the maximum element of an array of values?

For example:

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
sampleArray = [1, 5, 2, 9, 4, 6, 3]
```

I want a function that returns the integer of 3 that tells me that `sampleArray[3]` is the largest value in the array.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

In the STL, [`std::max_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) provides the iterator (which can be used to get index with [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), if you really want it).

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int A[4] = {0, 2, 3, 1};
  const int N = sizeof(A) / sizeof(int);

  cout << "Index of max element: "
       << distance(A, max_element(A, A + N))
       << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of using the function distance()?

Comment: According to the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), it's complexity scales linearly _unless_ the provided iterator is a `RandomAccessIterator`, in which case it is constant in time. In any case, the optimization is done internally for you.

Answer (score 46):

Or, written in one line:

```
std::cout << std::distance(sampleArray.begin(),std::max_element(sampleArray.begin(), sampleArray.end()));
```

Comment: This does not work with arrays, which the question suggests as the generic structure to be used, since arrays aren't class types and therefore they have have no member functions such as .begin() or .end().
I think you can adapt your code by using std::begin(sampleArray) and std::end(sampleArray) instead of sampleArray.begin() and sampleArray.end() if you are using a compiler that is recent enough, though I personally prefer the accepted answer as it would run no matter which version of C++ is used

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `max_element()` function to find the position of the maximum element.

```
int main()
{
    int num, arr[10];        

    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    cout << "Max element Index: " << max_element(arr, arr + num) - arr;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`std::max_element`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/) takes two iterators delimiting a sequence and returns an iterator pointing to the maximal element in that sequence. You can additionally pass a predicate to the function that defines the ordering of elements.

Answer (score 0):

STL has a max_elements function.
Here is an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/

Answer (score 0):

```
cout<<max_element(arr.begin(), arr.end()) - arr.begin();
```

Comment: I'm afraid this does not add anything new to the already existing answers, and does not answer OP's question, which was about C-style arrays. Next time, please read existing answers and at least scan through the comments to them.

Comment: Sorry to make you upset. I was searching for a C++ styled solution but I found "rashedcs's" explanation which is best suited for C styling. I just taken help from his code snippet to write in C++

Comment: I'm not upset :-) . And the most C++-like solution to me reads `std::distance(begin(A), std::max_element(begin(A), end(A)))`, which works for C-style arrays as well as for STL containers; for arrays it can be reduced to `std::distance(A, max_element(A, A+N))`, as seen in the accepted answer.

Comment: zkoza has some point, but anyways this is different than existing answer :)